# Can't write out indexer's first value

Tags: c#, indexing

I am supposed to write a code where the user can give the program the number of indexes, and then give every single one of them values. The problem is, when I try to write the values out, the first value is not written out, and it also asks for one extra value. So basically, if you want to have 5 indexes, then the program will ask you to give 6 values, and the first one will not be written out.
What am I doing wrong here? I still need the "value" variable, because later on, I am supposed to use it in an else-if statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int amount;
    int value;

    Console.WriteLine("Amount: ");
    amount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("values: ");
    value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] tomb = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        tomb[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.WriteLine(".....");
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tomb[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Be sure to include your output.

Comment: What are you doing with your variable called "value"? This is the first thing you are reading in after displaying the text "values: ".

Answer (score 0):

The first/extra user input value is caught in 'value' variable. This variable is never used/displayed.
Just remove the line `value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`.

Edit :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int amount;
    int value;

    Console.WriteLine("Amount: ");
    amount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("values: ");        
    int[] tomb = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        tomb[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    int value = tomb[0]; //Get the first user input value

    Console.WriteLine(".....");
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tomb[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: But I need the value variable, because later on I am supposed to use it in an else-if statement.

Comment: Don't delete the line, just display 'value' and ask 'amount-1' user inputs.

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but I am a beginner, so how am I supposed to ask amount-1?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < amount - 1; i++)`, but see my response to better code.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("values: ");
value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

read `value` and store it. That's the first number you read. Then inside your loop, you read `amount` values and store them in the `tomb` array. Those are the rest of the numbers. Then in the second loop your write out `amount` values from the `tomb` array. You never write out that first input number from `value`.

So you read `amount + 1` numbers, and only write the last `amount` numbers

Comment: If you remove the line that sets `value`, the rest of your code will work as required, and another name for `value` would be `tomb[0]`. You don't need to keep `value` as a separate variable, just use `tomb[0]` in the later if condition.